# handle HTTP and gRPC request into Envoy

Tags: grpc, envoyproxy, grpc-web

Need to convert HTTP request into gRPC using Envoy. Backend micro service is working fine and it will support gRPC, but doesn't handle Http, so I need to convert request to grpc using envoy.

So the benefit is, both http and gRPC can handle together. Is it possible with Envoy, if yes, how can I do the configuration in  Envoy.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use envoy to convert HTTP to gRPC? I don't think to add Envoy complexity to you app is the best option. Is Envoy already part of your stack?

You can always create a simple HTTP endpoint which will get the HTTP request and call a gRPC method. It is pretty simple. Here an example in Golang https://github.com/apssouza22/protobuf-api-management/blob/master/services/apihttp/book/handler.go

Also, consider looking at the https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway

Comment: @AlexsandroSouza  Application is running with [micro](https://github.com/micro/micro) framwork with 20 modules  , as per your concern we need to call direclty to all module , also micro api have the ability to accept http requests and forward it to our services.. same only `envoy/nginx` does, but envoy/nginx have better ability to handle the request performance. I have tried both nginx and envoy as a gateway , but betting CORS issue

Answer (score 0):

You can see how to work with gRPC over HTTP using Envoy here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web. If you just need Envoy config, see one example here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/blob/master/net/grpc/gateway/examples/echo/envoy.yaml

Comment: its gtting CORS error , 8080 running with my envoy, 8000 client app `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.1.11:8080/com.foo.service.hello.Hello/Call' from origin 'http://192.168.1.11:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field name is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`